# What is the basic definition of \newcommand?

Tags: macros, latex-base

Awkward it is!
I can not find the basic definition of \newcommand, though it is used a million times.

I suspect it needs improvement.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 'needs improvement' part?I wonder what you are really after here!

Comment: there are many alternative macro definition commands, notably those of the `xparse` package. Changing `\newcommand` would most likely break most existing latex code so it would be hard to consider any improvements.

Comment: @Joseph Wright @ David Carlisle First of all I would like to see the genuine definition of \newcommand

Comment: I put the location in the answer below, but you can always use `\show\newcommand` to see the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 838  of `latex.ltx` is the start of the definition.

```
\def\@star@or@long#1{%
  \@ifstar
   {\let\l@ngrel@x\relax#1}%
   {\let\l@ngrel@x\long#1}}

\let\l@ngrel@x\relax
\def\newcommand{\@star@or@long\new@command}
\def\new@command#1{%
  \@testopt{\@newcommand#1}0}
\def\@newcommand#1[#2]{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar [{\@xargdef#1[#2]}%
                {\@argdef#1[#2]}}
\long\def\@argdef#1[#2]#3{%
   \@ifdefinable #1{\@yargdef#1\@ne{#2}{#3}}}
\long\def\@xargdef#1[#2][#3]#4{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{%
     \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{%
          \expandafter
          \@protected@testopt
          \expandafter
          #1%
          \csname\string#1\endcsname
          {#3}}%
       \expandafter\@yargdef
          \csname\string#1\endcsname
           \tw@
           {#2}%
           {#4}}}
\long\def\@testopt#1#2{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[{#1}{#1[{#2}]}}
\def\@protected@testopt#1{%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \expandafter\@testopt
  \else
    \@x@protect#1%
  \fi}
\long \def \@yargdef #1#2#3{%
  \ifx#2\tw@
    \def\reserved@b##11{[####1]}%
  \else
    \let\reserved@b\@gobble
  \fi
  \expandafter
    \@yargd@f \expandafter{\number #3}#1%
}
\long \def \@yargd@f#1#2{%
  \def \reserved@a ##1#1##2##{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#2\reserved@b ##1#1%
    }%
  \l@ngrel@x \reserved@a 0##1##2##3##4##5##6##7##8##9###1%
}
\long\def\@reargdef#1[#2]{%
  \@yargdef#1\@ne{#2}}
```